# Is there any function in rails to force string to utf8mb3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, emoji

I am trying to create a database record using rails ActiveRecord where the string includes emoji.

the string is `' Test-Shopping-Mall - Price Comparison, Coupons, Cashback Offers/Deals'`
in the above string, cart emoji() is there. While creating a record with this string it is showing an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x9B\x92 X...' for column 'name' at row 1:
```

I am looking for a function that can clean this string for utfmb3.